# YQL for twitter follower's tweets

Tags: twitter, yql

How can I get a list of the tweets of a particular twitter account's followers? I can get a list of the follower's ids with this:

```
select id from xml where url='http://twitter.com/followers/ids/sqlservercentrl.xml'
```

my assumption was that to retrieve the tweets for all these ids I should then be able to write:

```
select title from twitter.user.timeline
where id in (select id from xml where url='http://twitter.com/followers/ids/sqlservercentrl.xml')
```

but I just get no results.

**note** - for comparison the following query, which gets the tweets of friends (who I follow as opposed to who follows me), does work:

```
select title from twitter.user.timeline
where id in (select id from xml where url='http://twitter.com/statuses/friends/sqlservercentrl.xml' and itemPath='users.user')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the itemPath criteria?

```
select title from twitter.user.timeline
where id in (select id from xml where url='http://twitter.com/followers/ids/sqlservercentrl.xml' and itemPath='ids')
```